# Is there a way to get consistent error message from IE and chrome for min in input tag

Tags: html

I am trying to use min in the input type="number" but getting different error messages in IE (version 11) and chrome (version 46.0.2490.71).

Different wording is ok but what seems like error message on IE is wrong.
To be more specific, when I use min=5 and try to enter a vlue less than 5, the error message in IE says: "Please enter a value greater than 5".

Shouldn't it be something like "Please enter a value greater than 4" or "Please enter a value greater than or equal to 5" (as it pops up in chrome)?

So my question is: Is there a way I can create the correct message like in above line from IE as well? (Chrome is already showing the correct message)

Link to jsfiddle is: [MinDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/u1fzv0sL/)

or

[MinDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/u1fzv0sL/2/)

Plain html is:

```
<html>
<body>

<form>
  Quantity (minimum 5):
  <input type="number" name="quantity" min="5">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today.  I have an input of type=number, with min value = zero.  If the user enters -1, the error from IE 11 is "Please enter a value greater than 0".

Well...!!

Can you correct IE's idiotic message?  No.  No you can't.

What can you do?  Guide your IE users to use a better browser.  Or: don't worry about it.  One thing that is on our side is that the user won't see this silly message if they do actually enter the minimum allowed value.